# Safari inputs do not display text when typed into

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I have [this site](http://subscripted.gridprinciples.com) which, on Safari v10.0.3 (and also reported on mobile Safari but I can't test that myself), no text will be displayed when typing into an input.  I'm currently using a webfont, but even resetting it to a default font has the same results.  Neither placeholder text nor user-typed text is visible, but the text **is** technically there and the cursor is visible as it moves in response to input.

I've also tried resetting my styling to default browser / Bootstrap 3 styles, with the same results.

Inputs work properly on Chrome and Firefox.

Edit: it's like the text is invisible.  It's definitely not a color issue as I've already tried changing the CSS to various colors to no effect.  It isn't a z-index issue either.

Edit 2: the styling of the site is modified Bootstrap 3 with an added webfont generated by FontSquirrel.  I haven't encountered this on any of more than a dozen other sites I've made with the same tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Greg. I think you should provide a bit more information if you want to get some help. You can read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I followed everything you linked to.  Thanks for the welcome but this isn't my first time posting here, but I could no longer access my old account because I couldn't log in.  I'm sorry if my problem is a bit vague but I've exhausted every avenue of troubleshooting I know.

Comment: I got the issue in Safari 9 too.

Comment: @GregBrock: What happened to your former account?

Comment: @Badacadabra nothing that I know of.  I had posted a few questions and responses, but none of my normal e-mails seem to house that account.  I honestly do not recall which one of them was registered to that account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was fiddling around with your CSS and found that disabling the line-height on the class of "input-control" allows the text to show up.  Currently it's set to:  `line-height:4;`

Check it out:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIDVS.jpg

Comment: No worries!  Glad I could help!